# How to get the name of web browser in XMPP apps?

Tags: jquery, xmpp

I am a newbie in XMPP. Currently I am developing a chat application using openfire and xmpp.. 
When the user log in to the server, the server have to get the information of web browser that the user used.

Is there any method? I am thinking of using disco#info and disco#item to do that but don't know how to do...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to communicate software and version in XMPP. One way of deciding which method you want to use is to ask yourself what you want the information for.

If you are using the software version to detect capabilities in your application, you want to look at [XEP-0115: Entity Capabilities](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html), which does actually use [disco#info and disco#features](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html).

If you really do just want the name and version of the software as a string for reporting and display purposes, you could use [XEP-0092: Software Version](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0092.html). In an application I wrote that uses [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/), I used the following code with [BrowserDetect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html):

```
function version_handler(stanza)
{
    conn.send($iq({to: stanza.getAttribute("from"), type: "result", id: stanza.getAttribute("id") })
        .c('query', { xmlns: "jabber:iq:version" })
        .c('name').t(BrowserDetect.browser).up()
        .c('version').t(BrowserDetect.version.toString()).up()
        .c('os').t(BrowserDetect.OS).tree());
        return true;
}
```

and:

```
conn.addHandler(version_handler, "jabber:iq:version", "iq", "get", null, null);
```